# LabelEncoder does not seem to work correctly. How can I fix it?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, categorical

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h43ku.png)It all seems right to me but it doesn't work. The label has been converted to numbers but he sees it as not converted giving me this error message: **ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'veryhigh'**
Some idea? I don't see where I'm wrong. Thank you!

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np

 data = pd.read_csv('ohe_label_encoder.csv')
 data.head(3)
 X = data.drop('Class', axis = 1)
 y = data['Class']

# I convert the Class label into numbers
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
label = LabelEncoder()
data['Class'] = label.fit_transform(data['Class'])
data[:1]

# I convert the Color and Material features into numbers
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

categorical_features = ['Colour','Material']

one_hot = OneHotEncoder()
transformer = ColumnTransformer([('one_hot',
                                   one_hot, 
                                   categorical_features)], 
                                   remainder = 'passthrough')
transformed_X = transformer.fit_transform(X)
transformed_X.toarray()[:1]

pd.DataFrame(transformed_X.toarray())[:1]

# I train the net
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
model = RandomForestRegressor()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(transformed_X, y, test_size = 0.2)

model.fit(X_train, y_train)[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: You transform `data['class']` instead of `y` but then try to `fit` on `y`

Comment: it is more helpful to users of you enter the data and *not a picture* of the data.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I tried and I get another mysterious error that I can solve: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [10, 8]

Comment: Before and after the transformation.     before: X.shape, y.shape    ((10, 4), (10,)) 
after  : transformed_X.shape, y_train.shape        (10, 14), (8,))

Comment: I wanted to enter the data but not as well as it is here.